# When I highlight and 'f9' the components of an array formula it will compute the answer correctly, but doesn't work normally

Tags: excel, match, offset

So I have replicated the error with dummy data [here](https://mega.nz/#!pQ8XhbKZ!IJNrcgBVnIL5k5IzuK7PwIJJ_46gL33CuDLnPgeEb3c).

I am trying to populate C2:C5 with the totals from the value column in the rawdata table that correspond to the values in B2:B4 multiplied by the looked up values in type table.

when I highlight the respective arrays in the Sumproduct formula  and leave them as values they are calculating correctly, but for some reason the formula doesn't work as is.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(RawData[Value],--($B2=RIGHT(RawData[Vehicle],LEN($B2))),OFFSET(Multiplier[[#Headers],[Multiplier]],MATCH(RawData[Type],Multiplier[[Type ]],0),0))
```

EDIT:

I have a sumproduct formula with three arrays, the first is a column full of values, the second is a list of bools and the third is a list of multipliers.

The formula is returning 0 even when all criteria are met.

I have identified that it is the third array of multipliers that is causing the problem. If I highlight that section of formula, hit F9 and convert it to values, the whole thing calculates correctly. but when it is left as a formula it is returning 0.

Comment: It's tricky to describe, I'll try and be a bit more articulate. Edit incoming

Comment: Only reason I ask this is that most SO users do not have the patience to download a spreadsheet and study it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone in the future has a similar issue, I think it's the offset part of the function.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(RawData[Value],--($B2=RIGHT(RawData[Vehicle],LEN($B2))),OFFSET(Multiplier[[#Headers],[Multiplier]],MATCH(RawData[Type],Multiplier[[Type ]],0),0))
```

You can in this situation use sumif instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(RawData[Value],--($B2=RIGHT(RawData[Vehicle],LEN($B2))),SUMIF(Multiplier[[Type ]],RawData[Type],Multiplier[Multiplier]))
```

credit to /u/rnelsonee 
[/r/excel Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/4102ei/formula_calculation_not_behaving_as_expected/cyylcap)